# Transformar uma coluna em várias outras colunas num data frame pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Bom dia! Preciso de uma ajuda... já tentei vários comandos mas estou achando que estou indo por um caminho longo. Tenho este dataframe:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E preciso transforma neste:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primeiro, adicione uma coluna com um valor constante, depois utilize `pivot_table` (precisamos da coluna com valor constante porque para pivotar é preciso que haja uma coluna com os valores a ser preenchidos na tabela resultante).

Exemplo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Nome Fundo": ['FUNDO AAA', 'FUNDO AAA', 'FUNDO AAA', 'FUNDO BBB', 'FUNDO CCC'], 
    'data competencia': ['02-2021', '03-2021', '04-2021', '03-2021', '01-2021']
})

df["constante"] = 1
resultado = df.pivot_table(
    values="constante", 
    index="Nome Fundo", 
    columns="data competencia",
)

print(resultado)
```

output (veja que `pivot_table` preenche as combinações inexistentes da coluna constante com `NaN`):

```
data competencia  01-2021  02-2021  03-2021  04-2021
Nome Fundo                                          
FUNDO AAA             NaN      1.0      1.0      1.0
FUNDO BBB             NaN      NaN      1.0      NaN
FUNDO CCC             1.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Que maravilha! Sé tem gênio aqui! Obrigada!!!!!!!!